# Change links from scrolling on same page to pointing to different pages

Tags: html

I am modifying a site that has a menu with the following code:

```
<h3>Menu</h3>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a data-scroll href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#services">Service</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

As a user clicks on those links the user will be taken to the corresponding section on that page.
I need to modify this to allow for links that do not point to the same page.
I tried the obvious:

```
<h3>Menu</h3>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```

but it won't work. 
The status bar shows the correct link but when I click the page won't change.
Is there any special code I need to add (links on other places of the page work fine).

Comment: The `href` should begin with `http://`.

Comment: yes, sorry, I did that, just poste it wrong.

Comment: If you tested with the `http://` in the actual code, then it should work.  Did you try a jsfiddle?  You might also check to see if there is any javascript/jQuery on the page overriding the anchor.  Look for `preventDefault`, for example on the element `on` `click`.

Comment: What are the contents of `app.js`?  Do you see anything like `$('ul.nav>li>a').on('click', function(...`?

Comment: Or, just try turning off Javascript on your browser to test....

Comment: If I turn javascript off the menu won't appear, so I cannot test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93835/discussion-between-user79303-and-sablefoste).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed, Javascript (specifically jQuery `preventDefault`) can override the default behavior of an anchor (that is to say, follow it).  Therefore, check all Javascript for this situation.

Also, a link MUST have an `http://` in front of it, to define the resource type.  Links only work on the same page or domain if there isn't one.

Comment: I found some preventDefault() functions in the app.js function as you pointed out that prevented the link from being followed. This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear to me that

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Will not work because you should write it like so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Give that a try, if the answer is not this, then you should share with us what else you are doing on your site that we cannot simply imagine by the snippet you have shared with us.

Comment: That helps but you still have the same anchor tag linking to `www.google.com`, since this does not have an `html://` it will not redirect you to a new page, in fact it tries to find `www.google.com` within the domain of your site.... long story short, try adding `http://` behind with your `www.google.com` and see what happens